# PostgreSQL Median without using percentile function

Tags: postgresql

To calculate the median for even number of rows, I know I have to divide the RowNum by 2. I don't understand why I need the "+1" and "+2" inside "WHERE RowNum IN ((RowCnt ***+ 1***) / 2, (RowCnt ***+ 2***) / 2)". Can't I just write "WHERE RowNum IN ((RowCnt) / 2, (RowCnt) / 2)" instead?

```
with t1 as 
(select *, 
row_number() over(order by hourly_pay) as RowNum,
count(*) over() as RowCnt
from employee_data)

select *
from t1
WHERE RowNum IN ((RowCnt + 1) / 2, (RowCnt + 2) / 2)
```

Video of me explaining my confusion: https://streamable.com/mv2vj

Comment: Looks like a weird edge case handling for even/uneven numbers, but I can't quickly come up with an example where it would matter either.

Comment: Where did you find this code? What makes you assume that this is actually necessary - maybe it's a mistake by the author? Have you asked them?

Comment: Let ```RowCnt = 5``` (works the same for any odd number) you want ```RowNum = 3```. Since ```5/2 = 2```, ```(5+1)/2 = 6/2 = 3``` and ```(5+2)/2 = 7/2 = 3``` (integer division), you want **+1** and **+2** (there are no other possibilities).
Let ```RowCnt = 6``` (works the same for any even number) you want ```RowNum = 3``` and ```RowNum = 4```. Since ```6/2 = 3```, ```(6+1)/2 = 7/2 = 3``` and ```(6+2)/2 = 8/2 = 4```, you want **+1** and **+2** (because they are also feasible for the odd case).
They are just mathematically the fitting numbers

Comment: So this gives you in the case of an even number of rows both "middle" rows